# Autogenerated MsTest in design mode in Visual Studio, what is it and why?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, mstest, xunit

I am finding myself creating integration tests to test stored procedures in my DB. So far I have always been a fan of xUnit but for once I tried to autogenerate in visual studio the related MsTests.
Result:

[image]

Maybe I am missing something about this but here are all my questions and doubts:

1. what is this? I know this is an MsTest but whenever I look for "MsTest Visual Studio Design mode" I keep being pointed out to the normal MsTest framework documentation. Where does this come from and how to study it?
2. why does this exist? It's a boilerplate generating much much verbose code in the background. If I check the generated .cs file it contains lots of autogenerated code that doesn't say much and it's very hard to review and to manage.
3. why some people still prefer this approach than having full control on the code through for example a xUnit test? here there is only a UI, very much not flexible, allows you only to set strict conditions and doesn't prevent (or help you preventing) repetition of code.
4. eventually I don't mind the original plain MsTest framework and the reason is that it's not that far from xUnit and nUnit if you implement it yourself: creating a class, using the right attributes, creating manually tests, etc. But this design mode seems to be indeed an MsTest but yet so far from the plain ones! What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Coud you provide more details about how you autogenerate MsTests in visual studio?

Comment: @XingyuZhao sure, right click on a stored procedure and click on "create unit tests..."